# Function not defined when running tests in Python package

Tags: python, testing

I am creating a Python **package/library**. My **directory structure** looks like this:

```
my_package/
|-- my_package/
|   |-- tests/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- my_tests.py
|   |   
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- main.py
|
|-- setup.py
```

I have all my functions in the **main.py** file:

```
def sum_nums(a,b):
    res = a + b
    return(res)

def mult_nums(a,b):
    res = a * b
    return(res)

def sub_nums(a,b):
    res = a - b
    return(res)
```

**my_tests.py** looks like this:

```
from unittest import TestCase

import my_package

def test_sum():
    assert sum_nums(3,4) == 7

def test_mult():
    assert mult_nums(3,4) == 12

def test_sub():
    assert sub_nums(3,4) == -1
```

When I run my tests from the package root directory as follows:

```
python setup.py test
```

... I get the following **error**:

```
NameError: name 'sum_nums' is not defined
```

- Is my package directory structure correct?
- Am I missing an _ *init* _.py file?
- Does every directory require an _ *init* _.py file?
- Is it okay to place all my functions inside a single main.py file
  without using if **name** == "**main**"?

Comment: note that `add_numbers` is not the same as `sum_nums`

Comment: Oops thanks. Fixed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indicate that the functions under test came for the `my_package` package like:

```
from unittest import TestCase

import my_package

def test_sum():
    assert my_package.sum_nums(3,4) == 7

def test_mult():
    assert my_package.mult_nums(3,4) == 12

def test_sub():
    assert my_package.sub_nums(3,4) == -1
```

Answer (score 0):

tests should not be in the package so move it up one dir. See sanic or any other module in github for example. Your functions need to be available in **init**.py.  You can import them like is done in sanic.

https://github.com/huge-success/sanic

You also need

```
from my_package import sum_nums, mult_nums, sub_nums
```

Or prefix with my_package.

Comment: I don't believe the functions need to be inside init.py...I was able to import the file and test them according to stephen's answer